# Angular JS - on page load - arranging array in ascending order

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, predicate, angularjs-orderby

Is there a way that I can arrange a simple array like below:

```
<div ng-init="fruits=['apple','orange','mango','banana','pineapple','kiwi']">
```

in ascending order on page load

I tried this, but it dint work:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | orderBy:predicate='fruit'">{{fruit}}</li>
</ul>
```

I'm sure there must be some pretty simple ways but since I'm a novice in Angular, would like help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predicate='fruit'` is not a valid `orderBy` expression (at least not a meaningful one, anyway). To `orderBy` items in an array as strings, use [`'toString()'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) as the predicate...

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | orderBy:'toString()'">{{fruit}}</li>
</ul>
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZW85p/)

Comment: Great! I've learnt something new and I'm happy about that! Thanks Anthony Chu :)